# How to retrieve all records of joined table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 2 tables: `customer` and `purchase`. I want to get a customer and all of their purchases with certain filters on the purchases; however; I want to get all of the purchase records if any match the filters.

For example, if I have John Doe with one purchase on `01/02/19` and another purchase on `10/01/2019`

Currently I am doing this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer LEFT JOIN Purchase 
on purchase ON purchase.customer_id = customer.id 
AND purchase.purchase_date = '2019-02-01'
```

However, this only retrieves that single purchase; is there a way to retrieve ALL purchases when only one matches the criteria?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a fact: '*' and 'LEFT JOIN' can never sensibly appear in the same query (oh, I've just thought of an exception- but anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT c.*, p.*
FROM customer c JOIN
     Purchase p
     ON p.customer_id = c.id 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM purchase p2
              WHERE p2.customer_id = c.id AND
                    p2.purchase_date = '2019-02-01'
             );
```

Answer (score -1):

Is `SELECT * FROM customer LEFT JOIN Purchase ON purchase.customer_id = customer.id` not enough?

Or maybe you need something similar below:

1. If you plan to get all purchases using specific dates you can do it like this:
   `SELECT * FROM customer LEFT JOIN Purchase ON purchase.customer_id = customer.id 
   AND purchase.purchase_date IN ('2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '2019-12-03')` or `SELECT * FROM customer LEFT JOIN Purchase ON purchase.customer_id = customer.id WHERE purchase.purchase_date IN ('2019-02-01', '2019-02-10', '2019-12-03')`
2. If you plan to get all purchases within a date range:

`SELECT * FROM customer LEFT JOIN Purchase ON purchase.customer_id = customer.id 
AND (purchase.purchase_date BETWEEN '2019-02-01' AND '2019-02-10')`

**NOTE that the parenthesis is important**

3. If you plan to get all purchases of customers whatever the purchase date is, this should be enough:

`SELECT * FROM customer LEFT JOIN Purchase ON purchase.customer_id = customer.id`

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with a join like this:

```
SELECT c.*, pc.* 
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT customer_id 
   FROM purchase 
   WHERE purchase_date = '2019-02-01' 
) AS p0                                                     -- The filtered purchase(s)
INNER JOIN customer AS c ON p0.customer_id = c.customer_id  -- The customers who made those purchases
INNER JOIN Purchase AS pc ON c.customer_id = pc.customer_id -- All purchases by those customers
;
```

Technically, if you don't actually care about customer data, you can skip that table altogether.

The subquery is needed because if the customer made multiple purchases satisfying the p0 criteria, a direct join would generate multiple copies of their data.

or, you can use the same subquery like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer AS c 
INNER JOIN Purchase AS pc ON c.customer_id = pc.customer_id
WHERE c.customer_id IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT customer_id 
   FROM purchase 
   WHERE purchase_date = '2019-02-01' 
  )
;
```

The nice thing about this second one is that it reflects the natural language expression of the task a little more directly; *"get all the customer purchase data for customers who had purchases on '2019-02-01'"*.

The first one does too, but some might not find it as natural, and little more ambiguous; *"for purchases on '2019-02-01', find all customer purchase data for the customers who made them"*.